# pushViewController don´t work on iOS 5 to launch GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch

Tags: ios5, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am developing an iPad application using sdk 5 and storyboard. I´m following the [OAuth2] Tutorial and sample.[1](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

I have port the code to a Singleton. Create a new view everytime initSesion is called:

```
    viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                             clientID:kMyClientID
                                                         clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                             delegate:self
                                                     finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

//viewController.keychainItemAccessibility = kSecAttrAccessibleAlways;

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"en"
                                                   forKey:@"hl"];

//viewController.signIn.additionalAuthorizationParameters = params;

NSString *html = @"<html><body bgcolor=silver><div align=center>Loading sign-in page...</div></body></html>";
viewController.initialHTMLString = html;


[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
                                       animated:YES];
```

But, when another Viewcontroller call the simgleton, the view pushed is not display.

Teorically, a navigator Controller use a stack to show differents view, so, if i´m in the correct way, that function must launch the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.view, to log in using OAuth2, thats occur in the sample. But nothing happen.

What´s going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have a navigation controller, it could be nil. Use debug mode or put a NSLog:

```
 if(![self navigationController]){   NSLog(@"I´m Nil"); } else { ... }
```

If you have no created a navigationController, try use the singleton of the app to get it, something like:

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: What should i do to get the correct navigation controller? please help